# How to sort a Python dictionary by a substring contained in the keys, according to the order set in a list?

Tags: python, dictionary

I'm very new to Python and I'm stuck on a task. First I made a file containing a number of fasta files with sequence names into a dictionary, then managed to select only those I want, based on substrings included in the keys which are defined in list "flu_genes".

Now I'm trying to reorder the items in this dictionary based on the order of substrings defined in the list "flu_genes". I'm completely stuck; I found a way of reordering based on the key order in a list BUT it is not my case, as the order is defined not by the keys but by a substring  within the keys.
Should also add that in this case the substring its at the end with format "_GENE", however it could be in the middle of the string with the same format, perhaps "*GENE*", therefore I'd rather not rely on a code to find the substring at the end of the string.
I hope this is clear enough and thanks in advance for any help!

```
"full_genome.fasta"
>A/influenza/1/1_NA
atgcg
>A/influenza/1/1_NP
ctgat
>A/influenza/1/1_FluB
agcta
>A/influenza/1/1_HA
tgcat
>A/influenza/1/1_FluC
agagt
>A/influenza/1/1_M
tatag

consensus = {}
flu_genes = ['_HA', '_NP', '_NA', '_M']
  
with open("full_genome.fasta", 'r') as myseq:                 
    for line in myseq:
        line = line.rstrip()                                      

        if line.startswith('>'):
            key = line[1:]                                
        else:
            if key in consensus:                              
                consensus[key] += line
            else:
                consensus[key] = line                         
         
flu_fas = {key : val for key, val in consensus.items() if any(ele in key for ele in flu_genes)}

print("Dictionary after removal of keys : " + str(flu_fas))

>>>Dictionary after removal of keys : {'>A/influenza/1/1_NA': 'atgcg', '>A/influenza/1/1_NP': 'ctgat', '>A/influenza/1/1_HA': 'tgcat', '>A/influenza/1/1_M': 'tatag'}

#reordering by keys order (not going to work!) as in: https://try2explore.com/questions/12586065

reordered_dict = {k: flu_fas[k] for k in flu_genes}
```

Comment: On the problem line, you're trying to use keys that are not keys in the dictionary. Perhaps you want to make a dictionary with those as keys, and let the rest of the data be a nested dictionary.

Comment: How do you parse "A/influenza/1/1_NA"? Do you need to sort or lookup by any of the fields or just specific ones? Do you ever add or remove data from this data structure?

Comment: @KennyOstrom thanks. I have a text file where every line starting with ">" is the sequence header and the subsequent lines are the sequence itself which ends before the next ">" which will mark the second sequence header. The file will contain non-flu sequences, therefore I need to select only those containing the gene names in the sequence header and I also need to order them  following the order of the list "flu_genes". I will not add data. Also all the gene names listed in flu_genes will be always present in the file

Comment: It seems like you could pull out the gene field as part of the original parsing, and store all those parts as separate fields, making them all accessible for other stuff. But I guess that goes beyond the scope of the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A dictionary is fundamentally unsorted, but as an implementation detail of python3 it remembers its insertion order, and you're not going to change anything later, so you can do what you're doing.

The problem is, of course, that you're not working with the actual keys. So let's just set up a list of the keys, and sort that according to your criteria. Then you can do the other thing you did, except using the actual keys.

```
flu_genes = ['_HA', '_NP', '_NA', '_M']
def get_gene_index(k):
    for index, gene in enumerate(flu_genes):
        if k.endswith(gene):
            return index
    raise ValueError('I thought you removed those already')
    
reordered_keys = sorted(flu_fas.keys(), key=get_gene_index)
reordered_dict = {k: flu_fas[k] for k in reordered_keys}
for k, v in reordered_dict.items():
    print(k, v)
```

> A/influenza/1/1_HA tgcat
> A/influenza/1/1_NP ctgat
> A/influenza/1/1_NA atgcg
> A/influenza/1/1_M tatag

Normally, I wouldn't do an n-squared sort, but I'm assuming the lines in the data file is much larger than the number of flu_genes, making that essentially a fixed constant.

This may or may not be the best data structure for your application, but I'll leave that to code review.

Comment: Many thanks @Kenny Ostrom, this works perfect. Hopefully will be a good data structure for me down the line.

Answer (score 0):

It's because you are trying to reorder it with non-existent dictionary keys. Your keys are

```
['>A/influenza/1/1_NA', '>A/influenza/1/1_NP', '>A/influenza/1/1_HA', '>A/influenza/1/1_M']
```

which doesn't match the list

```
['_HA', '_NP', '_NA', '_M']
```

you first need to get transform them to make them match and since we know the pattern that it's at the end of the string starting with an underscore, we can split at underscores and get the last match.

```
consensus = {}
flu_genes = ['_HA', '_NP', '_NA', '_M']
  
with open("full_genome.fasta", 'r') as myseq:                 
    for line in myseq:
        line = line.rstrip()
        if line.startswith('>'):
            sequence = line
            gene = line.split('_')[-1]      
            key = f"_{gene}"
        else:
            consensus[key] = {
                'sequence': sequence,
                'data': line
            }                       
    
flu_fas = {key : val for key, val in consensus.items() if any(ele in key for ele in flu_genes)}

print("Dictionary after removal of keys : " + str(flu_fas))

reordered_dict = {k: flu_fas[k] for k in flu_genes}
```

Comment: Thanks @Jen Chua, that worked great! However I have now lost the full keys which I need as they will be the sequence names. How can I put them back as keys, keeping in mind that I will have hundreds of files with different "full keys" (however the key = f"_{gene}" will be the common pattern). Is it doing a nested dictionary the answer?

Comment: You also nest your data if you want to store additional values like the original key. I updated my answer.

Comment: Many thanks for your help. Your solution works well, however Kenny Ostrom's answer renders a single dictionary which I think will be easier for me to deal with.